# static não compartilha valores entre usuários web

Tags: c#, .net, static

É possível eu utilizar uma propriedade `static` sem compartilhar os valores entre usuários diferentes?

Mais ou menos como *Session*?

Ex: do cenário:

```
private static double valorRetorno;

public CalculaValor()
{
 valorRetorno = //recupera valor do cliente
}

public Imprimi()
{
 Imprimi(valorRetorno); //algo do tipo
}
```

// lógica

```
Cliente 01 passa pela etapa CalculaValor()
Cliente 01 = valor 25,00
Cliente 01 vai para o setor de Imprimir()
Cliente 02 - entra no Calcular Valor
Cliente 02 = valor 30,00

Cliente 01 - acaba imprimindo o valor 30,00
```

**OBS**: Se eu só remover a propriedade `static` o imprime terá o `valorRetorno` como zero.

Comment: Se queres algo "mais ou menos como Session", porque não usar session?

Comment: Por que estático?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível, o `static` justamente indica um compartilhamento do dado por toda aplicação. Com este modificador o membro passa ser único para a classe e todas as instâncias a acessam.

Não sei se entendi o que você deseja mas a solução neste caso parece ser manter o membro como parte da instância. Talvez ele deva ser usado de outra forma, só com o que está na pergunta não dá para saber a forma correto de uso. E não sei se é importante para o problema.

Não vou comentar sobre o fato de estar [usando um valor monetário como `double`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

Comment: foi um exemplo, usaria decimal ou algo parecido..
Se não fosse possível criar a instancia dentro do imprimir, então não teria Solução somente uma Session, mas que dai é sempre string