# Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?

Tags: característica-linguagem, float, independente-de-linguagem, decimal, double

Desde os tempos de faculdade não consigo entender a real diferença entre o tipo `DOUBLE` e `FLOAT`, acabei encontrando o tipo `DECIMAL` que também trata valores reais.

Sobre o tipo `DECIMAL`, encontrei a seguinte afirmação:

> Para qualquer cálculo que envolva *dinheiro ou finanças*, o tipo
> `Decimal` deve ser sempre utilizado. Só este tipo tem a precisão
> adequada para evitar os erros críticos de arredondamento.
>
> ## Por quê?
>
> O tipo de dados Decimal é simplesmente um tipo de ponto flutuante que
> é representado internamente como base 10 ao invés de base dois.

Em quais situações esses tipos devem ser usados de forma correta?
Poderiam me explicar o porquê do tipo decimal ser o ideal quando se tem dinheiro envolvido? Qual a diferença entre ambos?

Comment: `DECIMAL` normalmente não vejo como ponto flutuante, mas como ponto fixo. Por exemplo, no sql server, é assim que funciona

Comment: De uma olhada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11340/que-tipo-de-dados-double-float-ou-decimal-eu-deveria-usar-para-representar-mo

Comment: Eu creio que o tipo `DECIMAL` seja dependente de linguagem :/

Comment: @BrunoCastro será que é dup?

Comment: Marconi, você pediu independente de linguagem, a pergunta linkada pelo @BrunoCastro é de C#, então os escopos são distintos

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado sim, mas deve ser a mesma coisa pra ambas as linguagens. Todo lugar que procuro vejo mesmos cálculos.

Comment: Em Java e em C, procuro sempre fazer cálculos monetários com ponto fixo. No Java, uso o BigDecimal para tal fato, em C é um código que a equipe de Maratona da minha faculdade usava na época. Então temos referências distintas

Comment: A diferença entre `float` e `double` não é a diferença de bits utilizados? Geralmente `float` utiliza 32 bits no formato IEEE 754, enquanto `double` utiliza 64 bits. Ou seja, `double` tem um range maior e mais precisão.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Então vai ter uma especifica pra cada linguagem? Se sim, vou excluir a pergunta!

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não quer tentar uma resposta?

Comment: Decimal é dependente de linguagem e cada uma tem a sua versão. C# tem `BigInteger` e `BigRational`. Em c++ é necessario bibliotecas especificas para isso, tais como [estas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software)

Comment: Então, eu até disse geralmente porquê não tenho certeza se é assim para todas as linguagens. Preciso verificar. E no momento estou no celular, é impossível responder por ele. Quem sabe mais tarde eu faça algo, caso ninguém tenha respondido.

Comment: @Marconi não precisa remover a pergunta. Alguém com mais conhecimento de causa pode responder, ou marcar como off topic, ou marcar como muito ampla.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado tranquilo, grato pelas dicas :)

Comment: @Marconi fonte interessante -> http://www.macoratti.net/12/12/c_num1.htm

Comment: @Nosredna obrigado.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Os números não inteiros podem ser implementados com base **binária** ou **decimal**. A forma pode ser com ponto **flutuante** ou **fixo**. Claro até pode de outras formas também.

No ponto fixo o tipo já indica quantas casas decimais de precisão tem ali. O ponto fixo é menos comum. Em geral bancos de dados trabalham com ponto fixo, mas também possuem tipo de ponto flutuante. Grosso modo podemos dizer que o ponto fixo é como o `char` e o ponto flutuante é como o `varchar`, que, em vez de dizer quantos caracteres ele possui, ele diz quantas casas decimais devem ser consideradas.

Tem casos que você precisa sempre ter 2 dígitos, ou seja, só centavos, não deve ter 1 e não deve ter 3. Se você dividir 1 por 8, dá `0,13` (o método de arredondamento pode variar). No ponto flutuante dá `0,125`. Se dividir por 10, no fixo dá `0,10`, no flutuante dá `0,1` e é problema do programador cuidar para normalizar escala se assim ele desejar.

## `float` e `double`

A diferença entre o `float` e o `double` é a [**precisão**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precis%C3%A3o), ou seja, o quanto varia, o quanto consegue expressar um valor próximo do real, é o número de casas decimais que ele consegue suportar.

Esses tipos são chamados de **ponto flutuante binários**.

O `float` normalmente [possui 32 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) para representar o expoente e a mantissa, além do sinal. Dá pra representar muitos números, mas por sua natureza binária não consegue representar todos os números, então ele representa o que está mais próximo do que se deseja. Ele tem 24 dígitos de precisão e por isso é chamado de simples precisão.

O `double` geralmente é [representado por 64 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), então consegue bem mais precisão, mas ainda não a exatidão já que a forma de representação também é binária. Tem 53 dígitos de precisão e é chamado de dupla precisão.

Existem tipos padronizados, mais raramente implementados, até maiores [com 128 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) ou quádrupla precisão (113 dígitos), ou ainda [256 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octuple-precision_floating-point_format) ou óctupla precisão (237 dígitos). Tem ainda o tipo de meia precisão [com 16 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format) com 11 dígitos. Tudo tem o mesmo problema de inexatidão.

Esses tipos são regidos pelo padrão [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). Existem tecnologias que não o seguem, mas é raro. Há casos que o `double` possui [80 bits fora do padrão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision).

Os cálculos podem ser realizados por hardware ou software, obviamente o primeiro é muito mais rápido. Mesmo por software, como ele opera da forma natural para a computação, ou seja, binário, é muito rápido.

Muitos cálculos necessitam precisão, mas não exatidão. Então pelo computador se dar melhor com ele, use-o. Se for algo científico de cálculos pesados a performance faz muita diferença. O mesmo pode-se dizer de computação gráfica ou jogos. Haverá um arredondamento de qualquer forma, então a falta de exatidão prejudica nada.

#### 0.2 + 0.8 é diferente de 1.0?!?!?!?!

Mas se vai fazer uma comparação de igualdade já complica, 1 é diferente de 0.2 + 0.8. Louco, né? Isso ocorre pela forma como o número é representado internamente. Já 1 + 1 sempre será 2, já que não tem problema de inexatidão na parte inteira.

Se você não pode representar todos os números que normalmente um humano está acostumado lidar precisará de um arredondamento, isso pode dar uma diferença mínima aqui ou ali, ou seja, pode mudar 1 único centavo. Aí você multiplica isso por 1 milhão e 1 centavo vira 10 mil reais, dólares, etc. de erro. Não pode, né? Mesmo 1 centavo em contabilidade não pode existir, não bate mais. Um saldo bancário não pode ter isso. Tem estória contada que no passado programador de banco vendo isso começou pegar essas diferenças de centavo e foi acumulando na sua conta e ficou milionário (mesmo que seja só um *passarinho* contado, ainda ilustra o problema).

Já há uma resposta em [O que significa uma variável de dupla precisão?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177531/101) com mais detalhes do funcionamento. A Wikipedia e outros *links* contidos lá e em outras respostas *linkadas* dão mais detalhes para quem tiver a curiosidade de ver todos detalhes.

## `decimal`

O tipo `decimal` tem [exatidão](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exatid%C3%A3o), ele é sobre ter o número exato que se pretende. Ele indica que o número está em conformidade com o que se espera. Ele chama decimal por ter base 10 e não binária como os anteriores.

Cada tecnologia o implementa de alguma forma diferente. É comum guardar a parte inteira e decimal separadamente em inteiros, ou guardar tudo junto em um inteiro e determinar uma escala, ou seja, onde o ponto flutuante está, quantas casas ele deve assumir, em geral é um inteiro dividido por 1, 10, 100, 1000, etc.

O `Decimal`, que vou chamar de puro, costuma ter [128 bits de precisão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal128_floating-point_format) (34 dígitos), mas isso varia se for fora do padrão, o que não é tão incomum assim.

Algumas tecnologias implementam o `SmallDecimal` [com 64 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal64_floating-point_format) (16 dígitos), e o `TinyDecimal` [com 32 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal32_floating-point_format) (7 dígitos).

É comum também ter o `BigDecimal` com mais de 128 bits, em geral até ilimitados. Tem tecnologia que só possui este tipo decimal. Os nomes dos tipos podem variar em cada tecnologia.

Por ser decimal a performance não é das melhores, mas longe de ser uma tragédia. Em geral não é um problema por trabalhar com valor monetário e os cálculos onde ele é envolvido costumam ser simples, se comparados com científicos e CGI. Os cálculos são feitos com instruções de inteiros do processador, o que é rápido, mas precisa de vários passos de normalização do número, precisa prover algum arredondamento, muitas vezes o seu código precisa fazer alguma conta extra, então acaba ficando mais lento, mas nada crítico.

#### Arredondamento

Tratar arredondamento quando a exigência é de exatidão não é tarefa fácil, cada cálculo pode exigir uma política diferente. Pense que se você dividir 1 por 3, dá dízima, o que não pode ser representada com exatidão, então precisa determinar onde vai parar, deve ter 3 casas? então daria 3 de 0,33? Tá, mas se você somar isso dá 0,99. E aí o que fazer com esse centavo? Tem que ter uma política do seu código pra tratar isso também. Pode ser que o descarte seja justificável, pode ser que uma dessas parcelas receba esse centavo que sobra e fique com valor 0,34. Mas em qual? Precisa gerar um lançamento separado para manter histórico de ter feito isso? É na primeira? Na última? E se tiver vários centavos, ainda será na primeira ou última? Ou deve distribuir? Como? Tudo preocupação do programador.

## Sim, tá tudo errado por aí

Uma quantidade enorme de softwares faz cálculos errados, não só porque usam ponto flutuante binário quando deveriam usar decimal, mas também porque não sabem lidar com o arredondamento decimal. É bem difícil lidar com isso e muitos ferem legislação e/ou causam prejuízos.

Em geral usa-se o [termo de matemática precisa, mas na verdade o correto é matemática exata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101).

Ele não é usado só monetariamente, mas é o melhor exemplo de uso. Onde queira exatidão é com ele que deve ir. Mas um novato pode achar que exatidão sempre é bom a abandonar o ponto flutuante binário ou um fanático por velocidade só ficar nele. A decisão não deve passar por isso, use o que for mais adequado para o problema.

Acompanhe a *tag* [valor-monetário](/questions/tagged/valor-monet%c3%a1rio) para ver vários exemplos aqui.

Esse tipo também é regido pelo IEEE 754. Veja tabela retirada da Wikipedia

[image: Tabela de ponto flutuante IEEE 754]

Veja que os nomes oficiais só indicam quantos bits ele tem.

## Outras codificações

Nada impede de usar outras codificações, mas hoje não é comum. Uma que foi muito usada no passado era a [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal). Implementações fracionárias também são usadas onde o mais importante é representar com exatidão a fração em si, ou seja você não quer `0,333333333333`, quer `1/3`.

## Anedota

O problema do uso errado é bem grave e muitos sistemas estão assim atualmente, e está piorando. Está por toda parte, até em sistemas de empresas conceituadas. Se espalhou tanto que já dá para ver publicamente. Não é só um caso que se tornou público que teve problema.

Um banco bem conhecido, inclusive por contratar bons programadores, por ter melhores metodologias, das equipes trabalharem em unidades e serem referência em tecnologia, cometeu esse erro publicamente de forma crassa.

Não se engane, só comete esse erro quem não tem apreço algum pela qualidade, que não sabe programar e não liga para isso. E que outras pessoas que poderiam impedir disso ir a público não ligaram também.

Esse não é um assunto avançado, é básico. Quando eu falo de fundamentos que faltam o programador, não é de algo complexo, é disto, algo extremamente básico que já eu já sabia na década de 80 quando eu nem tinha 15 anos e não tinha internet, acesso a bons livros, cursos ou um monte de gente para me ajudar, além de não ter computadores sofisticados. É básico nesse nível, não é que eu era um gênio. Talvez seja o que eu sempre falo, as pessoas estão acomodadas pela facilidade de informação e por ter tanta coisa errada sendo disseminada, que as elas julgam ser verdade por ser algo tão popular. É preciso mudar de postura para programar certo, não é pegar um ou outro detalhe, é preciso dar um basta para as dicas Miojo por mais bonita que ela pareça.

[image: Mijo preparado no prato como algo gourmet]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Você disse que o `float` e `double` tem 24 e 54(aqui não seria 53?) dígitos de precisão respectivamente. Li em um local que float tem 7  e o double tem 15-16 de dígitos precisão.O Decimal está entre 28-29 dígitos(só que com o calculo que fiz abaixo para decimal consegui chegar aos 34 também, achei até estranho). Calculo:  `log(2 elevado a 53) ÷ log (10)` para `double` e `log(2 elevado a 24)` para `float`. O que lih está incorreto @bigown?Tem como adicionar exemplos na prática?

Comment: Sim, foi erro de digitação. Você está falando da parte decimal, que eu não coloquei.

Comment: "Um banco bem conhecido, inclusive por contratar bons programadores" - não foi o caso do float. Um cara que erra isso num sistema vivo não tem o mínimo necessário pra ser considerado bom, isso é igual engenheiro que quer por prédio em pé mas não sabe calcular fundação. Não pode deixar nem ele entrar no mercado, vai matar alguém. E quem incentiva é cúmplice.

Comment: A fama permanece, e isso é o que importa hoje em dia</sarcasm>

Answer (score 23):

## Sobre *float* e *double*

Esses são tipos definidos pela IEEE. Sua representação é dada pelo sinal, expoente e mantissa. Sem pegar nos pormenores, se tiver 3 dígitos para representar a mantissa:

```
d0 d1 d2
 1  1  0
```

O valor da mantissa é 11.

> 11? Mas só vi dois bits ligados, 11 precisa de 3!

Sim, e tem o terceiro bit ligado. `d3` é implícito para números normalizados. E esse bit é sempre ligado nessas condições. A mantissa acima é interpretada como se fosse o seguinte número:

```
d0 d1 d2 d3
 1  1  0  1
```

O expoente vai resultar em um número qualquer dentro do intervalo. Não pretendo entrar em maiores detalhes aqui. Vamos assumir que o valor resultante seja `e` para o expoente e `m` para a mantissa. O valor final então é:

```
m * 2 ^ e
```

Como `m` é um número formado pelos bits da mantissa (deslocados para a esquerda para ficar entre 1 e 2), podemos reescrevê-lo assim (para `i` sendo a posição do bit e `q` o total de bits):

```
m = somatório b_i * 2 ^ (i - q)
```

Então, substituindo na fórmula acima:

```
somatório b_i * 2 ^ (e + i - q)
```

Ou seja, todo número de ponto flutuante representado por esse esquema é uma soma de pontências de 2. Devido a características matemáticas, todo somatório (finito) de potências de 2 tem representação finita na base 10, mas o contrário não é verdade. Por exemplo, é impossível representar 0.2 como um somatório finito de potências de 2; você representaria como uma dízima periódica sim, mas dízimas periódicas não são representáveis no formato `mantissa * base ^ expoente`, sendo `mantissa` definida por uma soma finita.

Como existem números que não são representáveis, eles são aproximados por números bons o suficiente. Com isso se gera um erro de cálculo.

Para cada valor de expoente distinto, há um erro distinto associado ao cálculo.

## *DECIMAL* em SQL Server

No SQL Server, o tipo `DECIMAL` serve para indicar números de ponto fixo. O que isso significa? Significa que estamos trabalhando com números inteiros a maior parte do tempo. A bitagem é fixa, sua precisão vai até o dígito menos significativo.

Sua forma geral é:

```
n * 10 ^ (-s)
```

Onde `n` é um inteiro (de 32, 64, 128 ou 256 bits, de acordo com a precisão escolhida; [referência](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql)), e `s` é a escala, um número positivo. Sua precisão vai até `10 ^ (-s)`, valores inferiores a isso não podem ser representados, precisando portanto serem arredondados ou truncados.

O erro associado ao cálculo é sempre menor do que `10 ^ (-s)`, muitas vezes sendo mitigado usando o arredondamento bancário.

A multiplicação e a divisão exigem um tratamento especial nesse campo. A divisão terá o resultado arredondado ou truncado, assim como se precisa de uma rotina especial para descartar os valores irrelevantes da multiplicação.

## `BigDecimal` em Java

Se você está interessado apenas em calcular, não precisa saber muito além do que usar os métodos dessa classe para calcular.

De modo geral, ela permite um `input` de tamanho arbitrário com uma precisão absurdamente alta.

Por baixo dos panos, normalmente ele contém um `BigInteger` por baixo e uma escala. Ele tem a mesma representação matemática do que o *DECIMAL* no SQL Server:

```
n * 10 ^ (-s)
```

Sendo que aqui `n` é um número inteiro de bitagem variável (o `BigInteger` mencionado anteriormente).

O erro associado é menor do que `10 ^ (-s)`, sendo que é possível definir o valor de `s` em execução para ser grande o suficiente. Arredondamento bancário mitiga ainda mais o erro.

Note que aqui temos uma classe Java que fará operações que não são suportadas diretamente pela ULA, o que consome processamento adicional e uso de memória.

## `Decimal` em C#

Não tenho muito a falar sobre isso por falta de vivência. Mas pelo que eu li, ele se parece muito com o *DECIMAL* do SQL Server.

## Como usar cada uma?

Caso você precise de precisão no cálculo até certa escala, independente do valor sendo calculado, você está no caso de usar um `BigDecimal` ou equivalente. Em um sistema de vendas que eu presto suporte, usamos `BigDecimal` com precisão que varia de 6 a 30 dígitos (normalmente 30 para divisões, 6 para todas as outras operações). Nossos valores obtidos de imposto nunca foi tão preciso depois de migrar 100% do cálculo para essas especificações.

*float* e *double* são mais rápidos, eficientes e econômicos do que os `BigDecimal`s do Java; não posso afirmar muito sobre o `Decimal` do C#, mas creio que para multiplicação seja muito mais leve. Normalmente, nos processadores mais modernos, existe um núcleo de processamento de aritmética de ponto flutuante. Usando esse tipo de variável, o erro incorrido é proporcional ao valor mais significativo da mantissa. Isso quer dizer que um valor de 1 que aceita um erro de `2 ^ -4` significa que o valor de 0.25 aceita um erro de `2 ^ -6`.

## Cálculo de 30% de imposto

Vamos colocar um exemplo de cálculo de imposto para exemplificar o erro associado ao cálculo de ambos os tipos de dados.

Digamos que vendamos gatos persas. O imposto que incide sobre eles é 30%. Sabendo que eu vendi 72 gatos a 524.7500 cada, Quanto devo pagar para o governo de
Imposto?

Aplicar 30% significa multiplicar por 0.3.

### Java e `BigDecimal`

30% de imposto é 30 deslocado 2 casas para a esquerda (ou 3 deslocado uma casa para a esquerda). Como é um número inteiro, e não houve divisão alguma, não houve perda de precisão. Multiplico isso por 72, um inteiro que posso representar sem perder precisão com o `BigDecimal`. 524.7500 é equivalente a 52475 deslocado duas casas para a esquerda. Ao todo, após as multiplicações, teremos um valor inteiro não arredondado/valor inteiro exato deslocado quatro casas para a esquerda.

### Cálculo com *float*

524.75 é representado pela seguinte soma de potências de 2:

```
512 + 8 + 4 + 0.5 + 0.25
```

Ou então:

```
2^9 + 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^-1 + 2^-2
```

Conseguimos representar sem perda de dados se houver 11 bits para a mantissa.

> #### Por que 11 dígitos de mantissa?
>
> Eu estava relendo essa publicação e fiquei na dúvida "por que 11? Não deveriam ser 12?" Afinal, estamos trabalhando com dígitos das posições 9 até a posição -2. Isso resulta em 12 casas! Mais especificamente, ordenado por significância: 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2.
>
> O que eu mesmo havia esquecido era que o dígito mais significativo em números não denormalizados tem o valor implícito 1. Isso significa que não é necessário armazenar o dígito da posição 9, apenas os das posições 8 até a posição -2.

Precisamos multiplicar esse valor por 72, que é um valor inteiro portanto trivialmente sabemos que é uma soma de potências de 2.

O resultado disso, então, é multiplicado por 0.3. 0.3 não tem representação finita como soma de potências de 2, portanto ele será representado por um número próximo o suficiente, mas não exato. Se tiver 11 bits para a mantissa, a precisão do número resultado da representação de 0.3 é de `2 ^ -13`, o que significa que o representante terá erro da ordem de `2 ^ -13`.

Viu como em um simples cálculo foi possível inserir um erro em uma representação mas não em outra?

## *Infinite Series* sobre ponto flutuante

Se tem um canal do YouTube que vale a pena acompanhar é o [Infinite Series](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCs4aHmggTfFrpkPcWSaBN9g). Recentemente, eles subiram semana passada um vídeo falando de como se dá a [computação de ponto flutuante](https://youtu.be/pQs_wx8eoQ8), e um dos exemplos dados é que `0.1 + 0.1 != 0.2`, pois `0.1` em binário é uma dizima periódica e, portanto, não pode ser representado na notação científica (usando mantissa finita) na base 2. Esse é um dos principais argumentos contra usar aritmética de pontos flutuantes para resolver questões que envolvam dinheiro.

Ressaltando aqui, o `BigDecimal` do Java e muitos outros esquemas se utilizam de inteiros de tamanho arbitrário para representar mantissas, depois coloca a vírgula decimal em qualquer ponto desse número. Apesar de finito, como esse esquema de cálculo permite uma precisão arbitrária de `p` casas (portanto erro de `5 * 10 ^ -(p+1)` ao se fazer cálculos), temos certeza no cálculo dessas quantias (ie, `0.1 + 0.1 = 0.2` quando se tem `p >= 1`) na precisão escolhida.

## *Computerphile* sobre ponto flutuante

O canal Computerphile ("computadófilo" em interpretação livre) [comenta](https://youtu.be/PZRI1IfStY0) que número de ponto flutuante é apenas notação científica em base 2, com uma limitação de representação. E que isso é ótimo para representar grandezas tão grandes quanto o tamanho do universo e a distância entre o núcleo atômico e o orbital de um elétron.

Nesses casos, a notação científica é benéfica pois ela consegue representar significativamente os números e os erros do arredondamento do cálculo estão dentro do esperado. Os erros do arredondamento desses cálculos por vezes pode ser menor do que o erro inerente da medição de certas grandezas (adendo meu, o canal não comenta isso, mas é verdade sim).

Sobre os erros nos cálculos, o exemplo que o apresentador fornece é na renderização de gráficos 3D de um jogo. Se por acaso o a renderização de um elemento gráfico esteja deslocado um centésimo ou um milésimo de pixel, esse erro é aceitável e facilmente ignorado na percepção do jogador.

Em um ponto do vídeo, o apresentador fala de um exemplo de cálculo financeiro com ponto flutuante. Somar `0.1` com `0.2` dá um erro de cálculo inaceitável para aplicações financeiras. Então, ele sugere trabalhar com inteiros (na unidade dos centavos ou uma fração dos centavos) ou então usar o `decimal` proveniente na sua linguagem de programação.

Comment: Quem negativou poderia dar uma dica de como eu posso melhorar minha resposta?

Comment: Qual seria a diferença disso pratica quando falamos de PHP? Nesse Thread diz que não ha diferença alguma...

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/226826/em-php-existe-diferença-entre-double-e-float?rq=1

Comment: @HananiaMizrahi sobre `double` e `float` e `real` ele afirma que não há diferença. Não analisei a implementação do PHP nem fui a fundo em testes para refutar ou afirmar esse fato. De toda sorte, se houver alguma diferença é na precisão (mantissa e intervalo de valores do expoente). Já o `decimal` é um número de ponto arbitrário, no Java também tem tamanho arbitrário da mantissa, no C# é um ponto fixo com mantissa de 32/64/128 bits. Deve existir alguma classe em PHP que trate números do jeito Java/C#...

Comment: ... Você deve usar essa classe para fazer computações financeiras/monetárias, pois delas não incorrem o erro intrínseco de precisão da aritmética de pontos flutuantes